# Typoscript Split Wrap only when not empty?

Tags: split, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a `COA` where I need to get the second line from the description field using split. The problem is I only want to wrap it if the line has something on it. I tried using `required = 1` but it only works if there is no line at all (e.g. I have an empty 2nd line with something on 3rd line).

```
11 = TEXT
11 {
  stdWrap.field = rowDescription
  stdWrap.split {
    token.char = 10
    returnKey = 1
  }
  required = 1
  wrap = <h6>|</h6>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trim the white space away before checking the result with required.
To do so you need to switch to listNum instead of split due to the order of functions within the stdWrap tool kit:

```
10 = COA
10 {
  stdWrap.wrap = <h6>|</h6>
  stdWrap.required=1
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    field = rowDescription
    listNum = 1
    listNum.splitChar = 10
    trim = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know listNum was a thing, so thanks for that. However the trim doesn't seem to do anything, so I have the same result.

Comment: Could you post the actual string here? Since within stdWrap trim is definitely executed after listNum and it's just a TS shorthand for PHP trim, it should remove any whitespace around the value after the split.

If there is still something left, maybe it's something else than whitespace.

Comment: Well the textarea uses 4 lines which may or may not be there. I tested one where only the first two lines are present. (ie. you cannot even arrow down further than the second line in the textarea). But the wrap for the third line still renders.

Comment: Is there anything else in the DB field, that might not be visible in the textarea due to i.e. overlaying RTE configuration or due to other transformations done the content on the way from or to the database?
i.e. there might be an empty tag or something like that.

Comment: I don't have access to the DB. But it's a basic textarea with no RTE. When I was testing with `split` the `required` works so long as there is nothing on or after that line. Whereas when testing this it wrapped all 4 lines even when only 2 exist. So maybe the problem here is the config of wrap and required?

Comment: Edited the snippet, to make sure required will be checked before doing the wrap. Was not sure about the order of COA parameters, since wrap and if are the only parameters that are additionally available for COA besides the full stdWrap tool kit. Inside stdWrap required comes before wrap, so this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
11 = COA
11 {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    field = rowDescription
    split.token.char = 10
    split.returnKey = 1
  }
  stdWrap.required=1
  stdWrap.wrap = <h6>|</h6>
}
```

This would be my attempt to solve this. Advantage would be that it would be extensible and other lines or factors could be added to the list.

The COA would only be printed if any item in its list would return anything other than "", null or 0

Comment: Same result. When the line is empty the split seems to give a line break as the value. So I get the wrap with a line break inside the code.